# React / Redux issue with middleware / thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-api-middleware

I have a large react app that works great on edge, chrome, firefox, safari 11+ etc, however I am facing a strange issue on Safari 10 and IE11. The action/reducer for for login just does not seem to be called in the app in these two browsers. On login screen, button click works, but as soon as the dispatch is called for login action, it just goes into a void, there is no error in console, no network request. I have tried many combinations of babel polyfills, presets, transforms, and after much effort it has come down to the conclusion that it has something to do with the redux-thunk. SInce login never works, I am assuming any other network requests in app will not be working either.

Anyone encountered the same issue and found a solution, would be grateful for your help.

Thanks

Comment: The problem cannot be solved without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question is off-topic because it's too unspecific. There may be off-topic questions that contain clues to solve them with educated guess, but I believe that this isn't one of them. *dispatch is called for login action, it just goes into a void* - use a debugger, only you can do this. *it has something to do with the redux-thunk* - redux-thunk is dead simple so cannot be directly responsible for misbehaviour.

Comment: Wow. I tried my best to debug for a week or so, and when I failed, I posted this as an issue in the project github issue tracker, thinking someone in there might have encountered same issue and would help. They closed it and pushed me out saying its not a support system. Go ask stackoverflow. Now your reponse is just perfect. Makes me think why the world is just a wonderful place. Thank you @estus

Comment: *Makes me think why the world is just a wonderful place* - possibly because everyone asks constructive questions without being sarcastic? SO is not a support system. It's Q&A. I guess that's not your first day on SO so you already know how to ask questions. In case you don't, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . MCVE is required by SO rules for very good reasons. In case you're too busy to provide persons who could help you with necessary information, there are paid services where an expert can save you from some hassle and use remote desktop to debug your local project.

Comment: Believe or not, my comment was intended as constructive. Glad to see that it helped you to improve the question.

Comment: @Samnan I'll have to agree with the previous commenter, it is difficult to help you without seeing any of your code. There could be dozens of different reasons, and I don't think it's reasonable to expect people to put in time to answer your question if you're not showing a little effort as the asker. I'll take a blind guess: maybe your action code has a problem, could you share that part?